# Sort by varchar date entry in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-order-by

I want to sort my table by `DATE` which is a varchar holding date information like this:

```
January 06, 2023 // format is Month Day, Year
```

I want to sort by date but it doesn't work since this is not datetime. I've tried casting `DATE` but it doesn't seem to work. I tried like this:

```
SELECT * FROM receipt WHERE ID=? ORDER BY CAST(DATE AS datetime) DESC
```

I also tried `convert` but it did not work either, I must be using the syntax wrong.

How can I sort by date if my `DATE` entry is of type varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with the appropriate date format to convert a varchar to a date:

```sql
SELECT * FROM receipt WHERE ID=? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%M %d, %Y') DESC
```